# Null Pointer exception while capturing screenshot on Micromax Canvas HD

Tags: android, bitmap, screenshot

I am facing null pointer exception while capturing the screenshot on **Micromax Canvas HD**.

It is working fine on **Samsung Tab2** and **Samsung Note 800**.

I have used following lines of code.

```
scrollView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);                        
scrollView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
scrollView.layout(0, 0, scrollView.getMeasuredWidth(), scrollView.getMeasuredHeight());

MailAttachmentImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(scrollView.getDrawingCache()); //Showing Nullpointer exception at this line of code on Canvas HD
scrollView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
scrollView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
scrollView.invalidate();
```

Comment: Please post your logcat error.

Comment: I have added the comment where user gets an null pointer exception.